# Why BackRequested event will be triggered multiple times after adding async in UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, back-button

I have an UWP app and I added `OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)`, in a couple places. However I found one interesting problem. That is when I add `async` to some of the `OnBackRequested` event, I actually will get backbutton remember how many times it has been tapped. That is to say, the first time I click it, `async OnBackRequested` will get triggered once, and the second I click it, `async OnBackRequested` will get triggered twice and so on so forth. I'm wondering if this is an OS bug or anything else. And how can I resolve this. Thank you!

Comment: It seems like you're attaching your event more than once to BackRequested...

Comment: So before you add the `async` it was only firing once?

Comment: @Stamos I have a couple places has backrequested, any one without async will get triggered once, but the async one will get triggered multiple times. It actually caused by not unregistering. I think the unasync works because of GC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you forget to remove the handler of OnBackRequested.

When navigating to new page, I think you did:

```
OnBackRequested += .....
```

But when you navigate from it, you forget to call `OnBackRequested -= ......`

Comment: It works, thank you! I think GC did the job for me for those that are not async, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

To explain why `BackRequested` is happening twice when you make your handler async: It's because you are performing an async operation before setting `Handled = true`. When you declare a method as `async`, then when it performs an `await`, the method queues up a task and returns. When the thing being awaited completes, the queued-up task runs, and that task resumes execution of the method (until the next `await`).

The `BackRequested` event handler doesn't know that you queued up a task. It sees that the handler returned, and it checks whether you set `Handled`, and since you haven't set `Handled = true` (yet), it concludes that the handler didn't want to handle the `BackRequested` event, so it calls the next handler.

So what you're seeing is the combination of two problems.

1. You performed an `await` before setting `Handled = true`.
2. You have more than one handler.

You still have a problem: Since your handler isn't setting `Handled = true` before performing its `await`, the `BackRequested` event concludes that you didn't handle the event, and it will try to handle the event for you (probably by navigating to the previous app).

TL;DR: If you are going to do async stuff in the `BackRequested` event, make sure to set `Handled = true` before your first async operation.